# Substring into an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I'm wanting to store an a substring into a new array.

Here is my substring `data = line.substring(i, i+1);`

How do i do this? I have tried `String data [] = line.substring(i, i+1)` but not worked.

Thanks

Comment: If you want an array of one element, then `String data [] = { line.substring(i, i+1) };` should work.

Comment: I'd advise you to keep all the type information together though: `String[] data = { line.substring(i, i + 1) };` The ability to separate the `String` part and the `[]` part is effectively a legacy from older languages, and generally discouraged in most style guides.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) does not return an array, it returns a `String` so passing it into an array won't work. You can split a `String` into a `String[]` array using the [`.split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method. The paramter is the delimiting regular expression, meaning if you did `"Hello World".split(" ");` (with space as the argument), the resulting array would be ["Hello", "World"]. If you want to split all of the characters into their own index of the array, just pass in an empty String `""` as the argument of the `split` method (like `line.split("")`).

If your goal is to store the `String` in an array you can pass it in with a regular array declaration and assignment: `String[] data = { line.substring(i, i + 1) };` or just make a new array and pass it into the desired index.